# Spring boot 3.0.0+ @Override error in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I am following this [example](https://blog.tericcabrel.com/validate-request-body-and-parameter-in-spring-boot/) (**Validate Request Body and Parameter in Spring Boot** in **medium**) and this [example](https://medium.com/@tericcabrel/validate-request-body-and-parameter-in-spring-boot-53ca77f97fe9) to implement a Handler to handle the correctness of a JSON as a parameter. The concepts are somewhat clear but having reached this point the use of @Override for the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method gives me an error like: *Method does not override method from its superclass*.

I have searched online to figure out how to solve this problem but I am probably missing something.

```
package com.tericcabrel.hotel.exceptions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    Map<String, List<String>> body = new HashMap<>();

    List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
        .getFieldErrors()
        .stream()
        .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    body.put("errors", errors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I report the solution if possibly other people follow the tutorial. In the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#%3Cinit%3E()) the method (`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`) reports the class `HttpStatusCode` and not `HttpStatus`

Comment: Nice findings. Helped me a lot.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. There is a lot of small things when you pass from Spring Boot 2.7.x to Spring Boot 3.x. This is one of them

Comment: @Gianni it would be nice to mark this as an accepted answer

Comment: Very well, thanks. Works fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today.

I've solved it **NOT** extending from *ResponseEntityExceptionHandler*, replacing the *@Override* annotation with *@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)*, and removing the parameters *headers* and *status* from the method.

I didn't try your particular code. Maybe you have to modify it a little bit, but basically you should write something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, List<String>> body = new HashMap<>();

        List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        body.put("errors", errors);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted response seems pretty clear, however it was unclear to me in the beginning so the reason by which this error is appearing is because the method does not have this signature anymore:

```
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)
```

but has this one:

```
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request)
```

Notice the data type for status argument that changed from `HttpStatus` to `HttpStatusCode`

So changing the data type is required and will solve the issue.