# Spring boot & Spring WebFlux 3.1.5 - Invalid request content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Spring boot project that used Spring WebFlux for APIs implementation.

I use `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` plugin for Swagger-to-Java object generation.

When there is a POST request that contains a field that does not match on the Swagger API Spec, the following response is returned back

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Invalid request content.",
    "instance": "/v1/internal/create"
}
```

**The problem is** that there is no specific information about what is the field that causes the issue and what is wrong.

I remember in the older Spring boot version, there is such information. For example: The field ID should be a number or something like this

Based on what I found so far, it's because of security, to not be exposed to sensible information.

I also found two options that can be used to solve of the issue:

1. Enable `include-message` property (not recommended)

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

**Result**: Although I added this prop, it didn't work for me

2. Extend `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in `ControllerAdvice` like [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75690229/spring-boot-3-0-0-override-error-in-responseentityexceptionhandler)

**Result**: This way can be used if the class comes from `Package org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation` but as I work with Spring WebFlux, my class comes from `Package org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation`  where such method does not exist

So any suggestion on how to solve it will be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found what should be done to return the proper information which fields do not pass the validation

I use `ControllerAdvice` that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and after debugging found that those two methods are triggered during model validation

- handleWebExchangeBindException - In case there is some binding issue. For example, we have a number that should be in the range between 100 and 200 but the user sets 50
- handleServerWebInputException - In case there is some deserialization issue. For example, we define the field to be an Integer but the user sends a String

Example implementation:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@NonNullApi
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleWebExchangeBindException(WebExchangeBindException ex,
                                                                          HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                          HttpStatusCode status,
                                                                          ServerWebExchange exchange) {

        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, Objects.requireNonNull(ex.getBody().getDetail()));
        ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()
                .forEach(fieldError ->  problemDetail.setProperty(fieldError.getField(),  fieldError.getDefaultMessage()));

        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(400))
                .body(problemDetail));
    }

    @Override
    protected Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> handleServerWebInputException(ServerWebInputException ex,
                                                                         HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                         HttpStatusCode status,
                                                                         ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ProblemDetail problemDetail = ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getCause().getMessage());
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(400))
                .body(problemDetail));
    }
}
```

Apart from that, I use the `ProblemDetail` object which is the one used by Sring because I want to have a consistent error model

For example

- Custom error processed from the `@ControllerAdvice`

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String \"111A\": not a valid `java.lang.Long` value",
    "instance": "/v1/internal/tournament/create"
}
```

- Spring error

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Method Not Allowed",
    "status": 405,
    "detail": "Supported methods: [POST]",
    "instance": "/v1/internal/tournament/create"
}
```